# alert Window minimum one div is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs called "Yes" and "No"

```
<div id="object">
    <div class="object-content">
        I'd say
        <div class="confirm" id="btnYes" runat ="server" >Yes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="object-content" style="float: right">
        I'd say
        <div class="confirm" style="color: red"  id="btnNo" runat="server">No</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And one Comment button called "Post"

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPostUrComment" OnClick="btnPostUrComment_Click" runat="server" Text="Post Your Comment" Height="33px" class="ppig" />
```

When I directly click on the "Post" button I want to "Please click yes or No" then only user can post the comment. So the user first clicks on the yes or no divs after that they post the comment. Please anyone help me.

I am trying some script. Please guide me.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        var IsPost= false;

        $('.ppig').click(function () {
            IsPost= true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to maintain a variable value

give a class check to both yes and no button ok

then in jquery code what you have to do make an increment to the variable and do check

here is the example with the code

```
$(function(){
var checkval = 0;
   $('.check').click(function(){
   checkval++;
})
$('.post').click(function(){
    if(checkval>0){
    alert('you can post now !');
    }else{
      alert('you can't post now , check yes or no first !');
    }
})
```

});

[Solution is here](http://jsfiddle.net/wcrC9/)

Answer (score 0):

I will get you short answer.

First `Disable` post button if user clicks on `"Yes"` or `"No"` buttons then `enable` the post button.

**js Code**

```
$(document).ready(){
      $('#btnPostUrComment').addAttr('disable',true);
      $('#btnYes','#btnNo').on('click',function(){
        $('#btnPostUrComment').removeAttr('disable');
       });
}
```

**Note**: This is by using Jquery. I have no idea on `asp`

Answer (score 0):

Here I've got something for you.

I assume you are using asp.net

add an onclick attribute in you `div` so that when the user click it it will make the `canPost` value into `true`. (See the code below for the reference)

and on the asp button add an `OnClientClick` in order to access the javascript and add the `javascript:return verify();` in order to call the verify function in javascript and if it returns `true` the `OnClick` Event will execute and if false nothing will happen

so here is my code:

```
<div id="object">
    <div class="object-content">
    I'd say
    <div class="confirm" id="btnYes" runat ="server" onclick="yesPost();">Yes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="object-content">
    I'd say
    <div class="confirm" style="color: red"  id="btnNo" runat="server" onclick="yesPost();">No</div>
    </div>
</div>
<form runat="server">
 <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" Text="Post your comment" OnClick="myButton_Click" OnClientClick="javascrip:return verify();" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var canPost = false;

        function yesPost() {
            canPost = true;
        }

        function verify() {
            if (canPost == false)
            {
                alert('Please click yes or no first');
            }

            return canPost;            
        }
    </script>
```

I hope it will help you. Just try it in you project..

Answer (score 0):

Try Out the demo Here, Mind the css , haven't applied any

### **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EgJaA/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var IsPost = false;
    var clickedElement = "";

    $('.confirm').click(function () {
        IsPost = true;
        clickedElement = $(this).text();
    });

    $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
        if (!IsPost) {
            alert("Please select Yes or NO by clicking on them")
        } else {
            alert("submit with " + clickedElement);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```